# How solve $\lim_{x \to 0} (1 + \frac{4}{x})^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How solve $\lim_{x \to 0} (1 + \frac{4}{x})^x$?

Can you help me Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Notable_special_limits

Comment: @avs Those aren't really relevant to this one...this is just a dominance argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know (where all limits are taken from the right):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+\frac{4}{x})^x = \lim_{x\to 0} \textrm{exp}\big(x\ln{(1+\frac{4}{x})} \big)$$

Now, because $e^x$ is continuous I can bring my limit inside:

$$ \cdots =  \textrm{exp}\big(\lim_{x\to 0} x\ln{(1+\frac{4}{x})} \big) =\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln{(1+\frac{4}{x})}}{\frac{1}{x}}\bigg) $$

Via L'Hopital (the trick in all these problems is turning the product into a quotient which we know how to deal with), the term in the large parenthesis is:
$$
= \frac{\lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{4}{x^2} \frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{x}}}{\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{1}{x^2}} = 4 \cdot \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{x}} = 0
$$

Now, $e^0 = 1$ so this is our limit.  Hope this helps, and if you need anything clarified just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Taking logarithm we get

$x\ln(1+\frac{4}{x})=$

$x\ln(x+4)-x\ln(x)$

this goes to $0$.

and your limit is $e^0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (1 + \frac{4}{x})^x=\frac{\lim_{x \to 0}(4+x)^x}{\lim_{x \to 0}(x)^x}$$